# What is the appropriate way to describe an "ordered union" of sequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series, terminology, multisets

Given the  $\langle $**sequences**$\rangle$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
S_1 & = \langle \color{magenta}{D_1}, \color{orange}{D_2}, D_3 \rangle
\\
S_2 & = \langle \color{orange}{D_2}, D_4 \rangle
\\
S_3 & = \langle \color{magenta}{D_1}, D_5, \color{dodgerblue}{D_1} \rangle
\end{aligned}
$$

1. Is there a standard way of referring to the sequence ${C_D}$ constructed by recording the elements of $S_1$, $S_2$ and $S_3$ in the order of their first appearance (including multiplicity) *i.e.*:

$$
 C_{D} = \langle
   \color{magenta}{D_1},\,
   \color{orange}{D_2},\,
   D_3,\,
   D_4,\,
   D_5,\,
\color{dodgerblue}{D_1}
  \rangle
$$

2. Is there a standard way of describing the construction of $C_{D}$ from the initial subsequences? *e.g.* would it be correct to say:

$$
\underbrace{\langle \color{magenta}{D_1}, \color{orange}{D_2}, D_3 \rangle}_{S_1}
\cup
\underbrace{\langle \color{orange}{D_2}, D_4 \rangle}_{S_2}
\cup
\underbrace{\langle \color{magenta}{D_1}, D_5, \color{dodgerblue}{D_1} \rangle}_{S_3}
= 
\langle
   \color{magenta}{D_1},\,
   \color{orange}{D_2},\,
   D_3,\,
   D_4,\,
   D_5,\,
   \color{dodgerblue}{D_1}
  \rangle
= C_{D}
$$

I've never heard of a "union of sequences" (and didn't find anything in a quick search), but I'm looking for the correct way of referring to the ordered union of the elements of $S_1$, $S_2$ and $S_3$, where new elements (or repeat elements of a higher multiplicity) are added to the end of the sequence, *e.g.*:

- *E.g.* 1:
  $$
    S_1 \cup S_2 =
    \langle \color{magenta}{D_1}, \color{orange}{D_2}, D_3 \rangle
    \cup 
    \langle \color{orange}{D_2}, D_4 \rangle
    = \langle \color{magenta}{D_1}, \color{orange}{D_2}, D_3, D_4 \rangle
  $$

  *N.B.*: $D_2$ is not repeated, because it occurs only once in each of $S_1$ and $S_2$.
- *E.g.* 2:
  $$
    S_1 \cup S_3 =
    \langle \color{magenta}{D_1}, \color{orange}{D_2}, D_3 \rangle
    \cup 
    \langle \color{magenta}{D_1}, D_5, \color{dodgerblue}{D_1} \rangle
  %
    = \langle \color{magenta}{D_1}, \color{orange}{D_2}, D_3, D_5, \color{dodgerblue}{D_1} \rangle
  $$
  *N.B.*: $\color{dodgerblue}{D_1}$ of $S_3$ *is* added after $D_5$, because it is the second occurrence of $D_1$ in $S_3$ (*i.e.* its multiplicity is higher than the multiplicity of $\color{magenta}{D_1}$ in $S_1$); as explained in the context, this is analogous to recording factors of a common denominator with an imposed order.

---

#### Context

I'm looking for the correct way to refer to the ordered factors of the common denominator of something like:

$$
\frac{N_1}{\color{magenta}{D_1} \cdot \color{orange}{D_2}} 
  \cdot 
  \frac{N_2}{{D_3}} 
+ \frac{N_3}{\color{orange}{D_2} \cdot {D_4}} 
+
  \frac{N_4}{\color{magenta}{D_1} \cdot D_5 \cdot \color{dodgerblue}{D_1} }.
$$

The common denominator of the terms is the product of the elements of the $[$multiset$]$:

$$
 \big[
   \color{magenta}{D_1},\,
   \color{dodgerblue}{D_1},\,
   \color{orange}{D_2},\,
   D_3,\,
   D_4,\,
   D_5
 \big]
$$

However, I'm looking for the correct way to describe the ordered sequence of the factors:

$$
 C_{D} = \langle
   \color{magenta}{D_1},\,
   \color{orange}{D_2},\,
   D_3,\,
   D_4,\,
   D_5,\,
\color{dodgerblue}{D_1}
  \rangle
$$

as well as the correct term(s) for the operation(s) used in its construction.

Comment: I'm confused before we even get to the sequence. If the $N_i$ and $D_i$ are real numbers, what use is the common denominator supposed to have?—everything in sight is just a real number, and the fractions/divisions aren't intrinsic to them. Furthermore, if we were talking about rational numbers, the (least) common denominator probably wouldn't be the product of the elements of the multiset—that would usually be some non-least common denominator. Your question seems to just be about concatenations of sequences, independent of this (confusing) context.

Comment: Re: "what use is the common denominator supposed to have?" I was trying to provide context, in case I wasn't able to describe the situation accurately or correctly (because I don't know the correct terminology).

Comment: Re: "...the (least) common denominator probably wouldn't be the product of the elements of the multiset" -- that is why I did not refer to it as the least common denominator.

Comment: Re: "Your question seems to just be about concatenations of sequences, independent of this (confusing) context." -- 1. Not sure if your use of "concatenations" was meant as an implied answer to the OP, if so, could you please elaborate? I've never seen 'concatenation' used in this way. 2. Apologies if the context was confusing: it is the exact context I'm trying to describe (i.e. the ordered sequence of factors of the common denominator), and I wasn't sure the question would be clear / correctly interpreted, without it.

Comment: I don't understand this construction at all. What does "in the order of their first appearance (including multiplicity)" mean? What order are you talking about? Why does the purple $D_1$ only appear once even though it appears twice in the sequences, but then the blue $D_1$ appear again at the end?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan the short answer is "because that's the operation I'm trying to describe"; however, I added additional examples, to clarify.

Comment: If you want to define an operation on *sequences*, maybe the first step would be to avoid the $\{$ $\}$ brackets that indicate *sets*. Also, I don't see why there needs to be an order to the factors of the denominator, given that multiplication is commutative.

Comment: @MishaLavrov re: use of braces, that is the notation I was taught sequences with; if you feel it might pose a real challenge to someone reading it, please let me know a notation you think would be less confusing and I can update. Re: need for order -- that is simply part of the question, I'm looking to know if such an operation on sequences exists and, if it does, if it has a name.

Comment: I would suggest $(d_1, d_2, d_3)$ for sequences, but as you can see in one of the answers, $\langle d_1, d_2, d_3\rangle$ is also used. My second question was more about seeing if your application will let you avoid the need to define this ordered union at all, but if it won't then it won't.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Updated notation :) I posted that answer, but am used to that notation for vectors (which makes sense). Any suggestions on keywords I might try searching to find results in this area? ATM all I'm getting are results for sets.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Is there a standard way of referring to the sequence  constructed by recording the elements of 1, 2 and 3 in the order of their first appearance (including multiplicity) ... ?

I found a link to a part of [Reversibility in Natural Language Processing](https://www.let.rug.nl/%7Evannoord/papers/diss/diss/node58.html) by Gertjan van Noord that discusses the idea of a union of sequences:

> [71], and [72] discuss a relation called sequence union to analyze discontinuous constituents. The sequence union of the sequences s1, s2 and s3 is true, iff each of the elements in s1 and s2 occur in s3, and moreover, the original order of the elements in s1 and s2 is preserved in s3. For example, the sequence union of the sequences $ \langle$a, b$ \rangle$ and $ \langle$c, d$ \rangle$ and s3 is true, iff s3 is any of the sequences:
> $$
> \langle a,b,c,d\rangle\\
> \langle a,c,b,d\rangle\\
> \langle c,a,d,b\rangle\\
> \langle c,a,b,d\rangle
> $$

However, this is broader than the operation described in the OP and the example provided does not make it clear how repeat elements ought to be treated.

Answer (score 0):

(1) I think it's reasonably standard to call the larger sequence the "concatenation" of the smaller sequences. It's certainly an accurate term to use.

(2) I wouldn't use the union symbol, since that has a well-established different meaning for sets. I'd probably try to avoid a symbol at all and just describe it in words.

Comment: The operation illustrated by the example is clearly not concatenation.

Comment: Oh, hmm, some repetitions are retained but others aren't. You're right, I didn't notice that.

Comment: @GregMartin that is the part that follows the construction of a common denominator.